# Can't ping Mac from PC

Tags: macos, network, pc, ping

I have a PC running Windows 10 and a Mac running macOS 10.12.4 both connected to a common home WiFi network.

**Mac network settings**
**Firewall:** disabled, **IP:** 192.168.1.18, **Subnet:** 255.255.255.0

**Windows network settings**
**Firewall:** disabled, **IP:** 192.168.1.14, **Subnet:** 255.255.255.0

**Ping Results**

- Mac->Mac (other) = success
- Mac->PC = success
- PC->PC = success
- PC->Mac = fail

When monitoring `tcpdump` via Terminal on the Mac it is showing that the computer is receiving the ping, but the PC is not receiving a reply.

Comment: Then - after entering `sudo tcpdump -nni en0 icmp` (or en1/2/3) in the Mac's Terminal - open a second Mac Terminal window and enter `ping -c 3 192.168.1.14`. To stop tcpdump'ing simply enter ctrl-C!

Comment: @klanomath The ping to the PC in the new terminal window is successful and the original terminal window shows an ICMP echo reply in the log

Comment: I would reboot the router/access point then.

Comment: @klanomath reset all AP and router - still no response when pinging the Mac from the PC

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problems, tried lots of things and finally tried not only to shutdonw my checkpoint VPN client but also delete all profiles and one would'nt delete as it had some firewall settings enforced...sounded scary so I removed checkpoint completely and viola ping works :)    https://community.checkpoint.com/thread/6627-i-have-endpoint-installed-on-my-system-and-want-to-uninstall-it-because-a-virus-has-masked-it-from-view-i-cant-find-it-on-the-launch-pad-or-in-the-applications-library-how-can-i-locate-it-to-uninstall-on-my-mac

Comment: You saved my day, thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

**Mac OSX not responding Ping, fixed**

Hi:

I have uninstalled Endpoint Security VPN, after running uninstalls, my OSX computer responded Ping. I paste here the printouts.

~(master*) » /Volumes/Endpoint\ Security\ VPN/Uninstaller ; exit;
UninstallAuth::main - Passing following arguments: [/bin/sh /Library/Application Support/Checkpoint/Endpoint Connect/uninstall  --uninstall].

Checking preconditions...

Uninstalling Endpoint Security VPN...
No matching processes were found
No matching processes were found
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.checkpoint.epc.service.plist: Operation now in progress
rmdir: /Library/Application Support/Checkpoint/*: No such file or directory
rm: /tmp/trlogs_*: No such file or directory
Forgot package 'com.checkpoint.pkg.epc' on '/'.

[Proceso completado]

[image]

[image]